# AWS X-Ray TraceId not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, x-ray

In my AWS environment I am able to find Root X-ray TraceId in CloudWatch Logs however it is not showing in X-Ray trace Search

[image]

[image]

Able to find in CloudWatch logs using this Query